# Pentaho problem with Cassandra datastax driver

Tags: cassandra, pentaho, datastax, cassandra-driver

I'm using Pentaho 8.1 CE

when I'm using more than 1 Cassandra input in Pentaho spoon, most of the time (~3 out of 4 times), we get following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/internal/TypeParameterMatcher
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    at io.netty.util.internal.JavassistTypeParameterMatcherGenerator.generate(JavassistTypeParameterMatcherGenerator.java:62)
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    at io.netty.util.internal.JavassistTypeParameterMatcherGenerator.generate(JavassistTypeParameterMatcherGenerator.java:54)
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    at io.netty.util.internal.TypeParameterMatcher.get(TypeParameterMatcher.java:42)
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    at io.netty.util.internal.TypeParameterMatcher.find(TypeParameterMatcher.java:78)
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.<init>(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:67)
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.<init>(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:57)
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.<init>(Connection.java:1017)
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:116)
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:128)
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:806)
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.tryConnect(ControlConnection.java:252)
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:201)
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:79)
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.negotiateProtocolVersionAndConnect(Cluster.java:1619)
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1537)
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.getMetadata(Cluster.java:399)
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    at org.pentaho.cassandra.driver.datastax.DriverConnection.getKeyspace(DriverConnection.java:152)
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.cassandrainput.CassandraInput.processRow(CassandraInput.java:156)
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 - Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.util.internal.TypeParameterMatcher
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
2019/02/22 14:46:53 - Get cancel tickets.0 -    ... 22 more
```

Did anyone come across something like this ? 
We are getting this on a couple of workstations including Windows and Mac platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I updated `netty` version to `4.0.56.Final` in pentaho-cassandra-plugin and it fixes this problem. I tested this with `pdi-ce-9.0` and works fine and with `pdi-ce-8.1` (works better, but sometimes problem occurrs).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Cassandra library in Pentaho:

```
PATH:$Pentaho/design-tools/data-integration-8.1/plugins/pentaho-cassandra-plugin/lib
```

I had updated the `netty*` version `4.0.44` to `4.1.25` on my machine after that the Bug was fixed.

Comment: I am facing error related to driver for cassandra output component in Pentaho.


2020/03/31 17:36:53 - Cassandra output.0 - ERROR (version 9.0.0.0-423, build 9.0.0.0-423 from 2020-01-31 04.53.04 by buildguy) : Value 0 of type class [B does not correspond to any CQL3 type
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidTypeException: Value 0 of type class [B does not correspond to any CQL3 type
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [ANY <-> [B]

Answer (score 0):

Hi and thanks for all your effort.
I've tried all of your hints and they didn't work.

Finally, we've upgraded Pentaho CE to the latest release and it solved the issue.

Thanks again !